# Autofill static character in string to match string length

Tags: java

I'm using this method as a line separator in a console and I wanted to make it easy to pass through titles.

```
public class Test {
    private int consoleLineSeparatorLength = "***************************************************************".length();

    private void printTitleLineSeparator(String title){
        String lineTitleSeperatorBorder = "";
        String lineTitleSeperator = "* " + title + " *";
        for(int charInString = 0; charInString < consoleLineSeparatorLength; charInString++){
            lineTitleSeperatorBorder += "*";
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(lineTitleSeperatorBorder);
        System.out.println(lineTitleSeperator);
        System.out.println(lineTitleSeperatorBorder);
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test tester = new Test();

        tester.printTitleLineSeparator("Select Character");
        tester.printTitleLineSeparator("Select Stats");
        tester.printTitleLineSeparator("Select Display Method");

    }
}
```

Current Output...

```
***************************************************************
* Select Character *
***************************************************************


***************************************************************
* Select Stats *
***************************************************************


***************************************************************
* Select Display Method *
***************************************************************
```

Expected output...

```
***************************************************************
*********************** Select Character **********************
***************************************************************


***************************************************************
************************* Select Stats ************************
***************************************************************


***************************************************************
******************** Select Display Method ********************
***************************************************************
```

If the center title is an even amount of characters including whitespaces (meaning one side or the other will have one extra asterisk), put the extra asterisk on the left side so everything still looks centered.

Anyone have any ideas how to do this?

Comment: It's basic arithmetic... just use `consoleLineSeparatorLength` and `title.Length` and subtract them, subtract 2 (for the spaces on either side of the title), and divide by 2. (You might need to add an extra `*` on one side if the title and the console line separator have different parities.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer on how to achieve your output in away you can reuse in different cases (print out in console, write to textfile, use in logs etc). It's basically the same as the first answer, but building the output as String using StringBuilder and returning it. This way you can use the String for others places, too. I checked with your example output and everything fits.

```
private final static int lineLength = 63;

public static void printSeparatorTitle(String heading) {

    System.out.println(createSeparator(lineLength));
    System.out.println(createSeparator(lineLength, heading));
    System.out.println(createSeparator(lineLength));
}

public static String createSeparator(int length) {

    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    while (length-- > 0) {
        builder.append("*");
    }
    return builder.toString();
}

public static String createSeparator(int length, String heading) {

    final int position = (length - heading.length() - 1) / 2;
    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    while (builder.length() < position) {
        builder.append("*");
    }

    builder.append(' ').append(heading).append(' ');

    while (builder.length() < length) {
        builder.append("*");
    }
    return builder.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    printSeparatorTitle("Select Character");
    printSeparatorTitle("Select Stats");
    printSeparatorTitle("Select Display Method");

    // checking expected output:
    System.out.println("*********************** Select Character **********************"
            .equals(createSeparator(63, "Select Character")));

    System.out.println("************************* Select Stats ************************"
            .equals(createSeparator(63, "Select Stats")));

    System.out.println("******************** Select Display Method ********************"
            .equals(createSeparator(63, "Select Display Method")));
}
```

Comment: Also a nice solution. I like not having to manage the extra asterisk with an if statement.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like

```
String header = "Test Header";

int desiredLength = 50;
int split = (desiredLength - header.length()) / 2;

for ( int x = 0; x < split; x++ ) {

    System.out.print("*");
}

System.out.print( " " + header + " " );

for ( int x = 0; x < split; x++ ) {

    System.out.print("*");
}
```

This can obviously be improved upon, but the concept still holds.

Take your desired length, subtract the length of chars you have, cut it in half, then print them on either side of the string.

You will also need some special handling if you are using an odd number of characters.

Comment: Had to change the line `int split = ((this.consoleLineSeparatorLength - title.length()) / 2) - 1;` because it was printing 1 or 2 extra astrisk, then add an if condition to add another astrisk at the end if the line was one character less length than the `consoleLineSeparatorLength`. Other than that this worked. Thanks.